# GKE pod connectivity to Cloud SQL

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql

Please enlighten me.

**Current Setup:** Docker container running inside the VM instance - The docker container can connect to our Cloud SQL with all the credentials included in the property file during the building of docker image

**Future Setup:** I deployed this container as a pod on my GKE but it couldn't connect to my Cloud SQL. I am just confused, Do I still need to do an extra step like the guide below before I can establish a connection to my Cloud SQL DBs?

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine

Since the property file where all the DB credentials where package together during the building process of an image, I should be able to connect to Cloud SQL DBs from GKE pod right?

====

```
kubectl logs -f appds-d599f75d4-wn9x6

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up
```

Comment: maybe a ingress or ingress firewall blocking it

Comment: Have you checked if your pods have network connectivity? Please take a look on official documentation: [Diagnosing issues with Cloud SQL instances](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues)

Comment: Additionally please tell which example are you following from the link that you provided as there are multiple. Have you checked the access scopes? [Access scopes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/access-scopes#changes)

Comment: Can you confirm you are, in fact, running the cloudSQL proxy as a sidecar, whether you are connecting to the Cloud SQL via private IP or not, and whether you have any whitelisting configured on the Cloud SQL

Comment: Thanks everyone, @ArghyaSadhu is right. I just need to allow egress firewall rule to my CloudSQL then it managed to establish the connection.

Comment: @erlchamp can you please explain this bit more?  I have a cluster and cloud sql in same VPC network and my gke cluster is "VPC-native (alias IP)" enabled, I assume the pod should be able to connect with cloud sql without any extra work, but looks like container not able to connect to cloud sql, can you give me more insight on how did you setup the "Egress" and how did it helped the communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For private GKE clusters GKE worker nodes and pods running on those nodes access other GCP APIs such as Cloud SQL via [Private API Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options)

[image: architecture]